# iPhone : How to get the access to the default quicktime player that is launched?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube, quicktime

I am loading a YouTube video link in UIWebView and when I click the play button, it launches the Quicktime player and plays the video in it. The issue here is that the default orientation of the Quicktime player is Portrait--I want it to be in Landscape mode.

Even though my base view and the webview are both in landscape mode, Quicktime player still gets launched in portrait mode.

I thought I could get the access to the default quicktime player and change its orientation to landscape.

Comment: Good job tagging your question! A lot of new users really struggle with picking good tags.  Just a note though, "quicktime" and "player" were supposed to go together, for that to work in tags you must use a "dash" character (-).

Comment: @Cpfohl: That's true, except that there's no "quicktime-player" tag. There aren't anywhere near enough questions asked about QuickTime that we need to differentiate between the player and the full version.

Comment: @Cody, Yup, I know, I was mainly trying to educate

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this? I need a fix for this too!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718908/video-orientation-after-launched-from-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not the case, but what about intercepting the click on the link and play the video using mpmovieplayercontroller?
That's only a suggestion and probably not a real answer to your problem.
Good luck!